# Graphing an astroid - parametric curves in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

So I am trying to create a plot of an astroid in pgfplots which has the parameterization x = cos(t)^3 y= sin(t)^3 and tikz is giving me an error that it is giving up on a path and wondering if I forgot a semicolon, but I did not.

Any ideas of how I can fix this? Any help is appreciated.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis x line =middle, axis y line = middle,thick, smooth]
    \addplot[domain=0:2*pi](cos(deg(x)),x);  %this line works like a charm
    \addplot[domain=0:2*pi](x,sin(deg(x)));  %this line does not work
    \addplot[domain=0:2*pi]((cos(deg(x)))^3,(sin(deg(x)))^3); %goal
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: use `{}` : `\addplot[domain=0:2*pi]({cos(deg(x))^3},{sin(deg(x))^3}) ;`

Comment: @VincentNivoliers yes that worked exactly! why does it need braces here when other parameterizations don't?

Comment: from [the manual](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf), page 53, it has to do with the fact that you use round braces in the expression, and that round braces are already used to enclose the list of coordinates. This is therefore probably due the the parser used for mathematical expressions.

Comment: @VincentNivoliers, please convert your comment to an answer if it has resolved OP's problem.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `{}` : `\addplot[domain=0:2*pi]({cos(deg(x))^3},{sin(deg(x))^3}) ;`

As said in the comments, this seems to be due to the handling of round braces by pgfplot. See [the manual](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf) page 53.